# Downgrade 20.10 to 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, 20.10

I am having issues with battery, touchscreen, rotation, authentication and freezing problems in 20.10, I want to downgrade is that possible?

Comment: Not as far as I know...  It might be easier to download 20.04 and install it from scratch.  It should ask you to just install the OS.  So, your files in `/home` will be fine.  Of course, configuration files will be overwritten.